# Rails: How to sort many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between a model User and Picture. These are linked by a join table called Picturization.

If I obtain a list of users of a single picture, i.e. picture.users -> how can I ensure that the result obtained is sorted by either creation of the Picturization row (i.e. the order at which a picture was associated to a user). How would this change if I wanted to obtain this in order of modification?

Thanks!

**Edit**
Maybe something like

```
picture.users.where(:order => "created_at")
```

- but this created_at refers to the created_at in picturization

Answer (score 1):

Have an additional column something like **sequence** in picturization table and define sort order as default scope in your Picturization

```
default_scope :order => 'sequence ASC'
```

If you want default sort order based on modified_at then use following default scope

```
default_scope :order => 'modified_at DESC'
```

Comment: I noticed that picturization already has created_at and modified_at in its table columns (by default?). Can I use this somehow?

Comment: If want modified_at column as sequence order then you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the table name in the order method/clause:

```
picture.users.order("picturizations.created_at DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case, I need to sort many-to-many relation by a column named weight in the middle-table. After hours of trying, I figured out two solutions to **sort many-to-many relation**.

## Solution1: In Rails Way

```
picture.users.where(:order => "created_at")
```

cannot return a ActiveRecord::Relation sorted by Picturization's created_at column.

I have tried to rewrite a default_scope method in Picturization, but it does not work:

```
def self.default_scope
  return Picturization.all.order(weight: :desc)
end
```

Instead, first, you need to get the ids of sorted Picturization:

```
ids = Picturization.where(user_id:user.id).order(created_at: :desc).ids
```

Then, you can get the sorted objects by using [MySQL field functin](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

```
picture.users.order("field(picturizations.id, #{ids.join(",")})")
```

which generates SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT `users`.* 
FROM `pictures` INNER JOIN `picturizations` 
ON `pictures`.`id` = `picturizations`.`picture_id` 
WHERE `picturizations`.`user_id = 1#for instance 
ORDER BY field(picturizations.id, 9,18,6,8,7)#for instance
```

## Solution2: In raw SQL Way

you can get the answer directly by using an **order by** function:

```
SELECT `users`.* 
FROM `pictures` INNER JOIN `picturizations` 
ON `pictures`.`id` = `picturizations`.`picture_id` 
WHERE `picturizations`.`user_id = 1

order by picturizations.created_at desc
```