# Sort by a column in JOIN table of many-to-many relationship (rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a many to many relationship between `category` and `post`.
The join table is `category_post_relationships`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories, through: :category_link_relationships
    has_many :category_post_relationships , :dependent => :destroy 
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, through: :category_link_relationships
    has_many :category_post_relationships , :dependent => :destroy 
end

class CategoryPostRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

If I have a category, the category can query for all posts by `category.posts`. And I want to sort these posts by the `created_at` of the join table `category_link_relationships`. There can be only one record for each category and post. I want to sort the links by the column `created_at` of related relationship records.

For example, post 1 was created and associated to category A.
Then, the post 1 was associated to category B. 
Post 2 was then created and associated to category B.
category B now has post 1 and post 2. I want to sort post 1 and post 2 by the `created_at` of the relationships, not the `created_at` of posts.

Thanks.

Comment: first you should have to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, second: so you need get all posts in special order for one category? something like `@category.posts` ?

Comment: Yes. I need get all posts in special order for one category.
The special order depends on the `created_at` of the relationship between this category and each of its posts.

Comment: and now you can't change associations to HABTM?

Comment: No. I need this join table.

Comment: added answer, check it out

Comment: I have two solutions to sort a many-to-many relation. see [the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417901/rails-how-to-sort-many-to-many-relation/43781591#43781591)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :category_link_relationships , :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :category_link_relationships
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :category_link_relationships , :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, through: :category_link_relationships
end
```

and now you can find posts in next way:

```
@category.posts.joins(:category_link_relationships).order('category_link_relati‌​onships.created_at')
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to type something in my question.
The content of my post and category class is the same as yours.

Comment: not the same, you forgot `through: :category_link_relationships`

Comment: `@category.posts.order(:created_at)`
=> Sorted by the `created_at` of each post?
I want them to be sorted by `created_at` of the relationship between the posts and that category.
For example, post 1 was created and associated to category A.
Then, the post 1 was associated to category B. 
Post 2 was then created and associated to category B.
category B now has post 1 and post 2. I want to sort post 1 and post 2 by the `created_at` of the relationships, not the `created_at` of posts.

Comment: Sorry again. That's my typo.

Comment: The join table may have other columns so I need this table.

Comment: I added code to answer, please mark it as useful, have a nice day

Comment: Actually, there is something wrong.
Your command will return all posts. I don't know why.

Comment: I use
`Post.joins(:category_post_relationships).where("category_post_relationships.category_id = 2").order("category_post_relationships.created_at”)`
It works.

Comment: it's so huge `@category = Category.find(2)` than `@category.posts.joins(:category_link_relationships).order('category_link_relati‌​onships.created_at')`. It's more Rails Way

Answer (score 1):

If you will always order this way, you can use a default scope on the join table.

```
class CategoryLinkRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category

  default_scope { order(created_at: :asc)}
end
```

This will be automatically picked up by ActiveRecord. Be careful, if there is also a default scope on Category it will override the sort.